# How to Use OR in the ELSE part of the CASE statement

Tags: sql, case, foxpro

Here is my requirement.. in the sql CASE statement when the WHEN condition is met THEN part is to be executed.. if the condition is not met then I need to have two options to select from (meaning that I need to have an OR in the ELSE part)..

I am stuck here..

```
CASE WHEN 
   tablename.ID=0 
THEN 
   tablename.description 
ELSE 
   tablename.description2 OR tablename.description2 
END AS abcd
```

I'm doing a foxpro to sql migration, so encountered a statement in foxpro which uses '/' in the ELSE part of its CASE(called IIF in foxpro) statement..

I am assuming '/' to be OR in SQL

Any solution to meet this requirement please?

Comment: That logic doesn't make any sense. You do an "OR" on an expression, not on the results. What shows up in the ELSE is the value that you want to put in the field when the tablename.ID <> 0.

Comment: Can you post more of the query please

Comment: Um, isn't `/` in FoxPro [division](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0fh39279(v=vs.80)), the same as it would be in [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx)?

Comment: Further to you not being able to use `OR` on results, you have the same field either side of the `OR`? This means it makes even less sense!

Comment: my result should give out either field1 or field2 (different fields, sorry for posting the same field name).. if OR is not a solution in this case.. can I have an alternate approach to solve this?

Comment: You need to specify in what circumstances it would be field1 and which it would be field2 otherwise it is impossible to create a rule to determine this. The only other possibility that I can think of is that the `ELSE` should be `ELSE COALESCE(Field1, Field2) END` i.e. when field1 is null default to field2 otherwise use field1.

Comment: Damien, I assumed the same but that doesnt give me the results.. I dont know much abt foxpro so just trying out various ways to get the desired result.. Thanks Gareth I'll try if COALESCE works..

Comment: If its still unresolved, can you post the original IIF() statement from the foxpro you are converting from.

Comment: Hey I did resolve it.. '/' IS division indeed ! i just had to do some casting.. gave it a bit too much thought.. here is the IIF statement for your info IIF(table1.NO = 0, 0000000, table1.QTY/table1.NO)..

Answer (score 1):

If you have another condition to depend on, then you can insert a second case in the first's else section:

```
CASE 
    WHEN tablename.ID=0 THEN tablename.description 
    ELSE 
        CASE
            WHEN condition2 THEN tablename.description2 
            ELSE tablename.description2 
        END
END AS abcd
```

Is something similar that you would like to do?